# why do i get segmentation fault in 1st code but not in 2nd code?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, segmentation-fault, newline

I have declared an array of 10 pointers to characters.out of 10 I have initialised only 3.
When I print the array using `%s` following `\n` then it gives output as follows:

```
hi
hello
how 
segmentation fault
```

but if I dont use `\n` then it gives output as follows:

```
hihellohow(null)...(7 times).
```

can somebody explain this please?

---

**CODE 1**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char *a[10] = {"hi", "hello", "how"};
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    a[0] = "hey";
    for (i = 0;i < 10; i++)
        printf("%s\n", a[i]);
}
```

**CODE 2**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char *a[10] = {"hi", "hello", "how"};
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    a[0] = "hey";
    for (i = 0;i < 10; i++)
        printf("%s", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Learn to use your debugger.

Comment: On which operating system, with which compiler and which compilation flags are you compiling and running?

Comment: a[3] should throw some kind of error, isn't? Or am I saying something non-sensed?

Comment: i am compiling my code using gcc

Comment: But the version of the compiler, of the C library, and the exact optimization flags, are important (see the [answer by ddpmanik](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19449860/841108) for why)!

Answer (score 5):

As you said yourself, you don't initialize your array elements past the third, so they are automatically initialized to null pointers. Trying to print those null pointers is Undefined Behaviour and thus **anything** can happen (including a segfault as in your first example, or *appearing* to work as in your second example).

In both cases, your code is wrong, and it is pointless to try to explain why random things (again, segfault or appearing to work) happen.

Comment: i know the code is wrong in both the cases but i wanted to know that why does it give seg fault in one case but not in other.anyways thanx for reponse .

Comment: The array elements are initialized. They just happen to be initialized to NULL, and `printf("%s", NULL)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin Ah I messed it up. I never use legacy C arrays so it's no wonder I missed that, I made a good diagnostic but for bad reasons. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it may come from your compiler. If you use GCC, [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15685) explains that `printf("%s\n", s)` is optimized as `puts(s)`. The page shows a bug report from 2004, but I can reproduce the bug with GCC-4.7.2 under Windows. While `printf` has guards against null pointers, `puts` seems to have none, hence the different behaviour depending on newline.

However, as already said by syam, giving a null pointer as a string is not standard and can cause anything to happen. Here it's just that GCC is friendly, printing `(null)` instead of simply crash.

Comment: Great answer, but it is not GCC but the `printf` function from GNU libc which prints `(null)`! GCC may (or not) optimize as you suggest (depending upon optimization flags and compiler version).

Comment: True. I was misled by the fact the bug report was made on GCC bugzilla. And on Windows it may come from msvcrt I suppose.

Comment: The behavior is due to GCC. But standards speak of undefined behavior, so GCC's optimization is correct. However `(null)` is output by the `printf` from libc at runtime. And GNU libc is not coherent between `printf("%s",NULL);` which is writing `(null`) and `puts(NULL);` which is crashing. Both are undefined behavior per standards.

Answer (score 3):

Both cases are incorrect, they attempt to print the contents of null pointers, which doesn't make any sense. You are invoking undefined behavior where anything can happen.

The line `char *a[10] = {"hi", "hello", "how"};` is guaranteed by the C standard to get initialized in the following manner:

```
a[0] -> "hi"
a[1] -> "hello"
a[2] -> "how"
a[3] -> NULL
...
a[9] -> NULL
```

Comment: Normally, in partially initialized arrays, uninitialized items are set to zeroes, right?

Comment: @Archie Yeah I just realized this and wrote a completely new answer :)